# Who tried Ubuntu with Coreboot/Libreboot?

Tags: uefi, bios, coreboot

Is it difficult to get Core[Libre]boot instead of UEFI or BIOS and what advantages (integration with Ubuntu etc.) can I get?

Answer (score 1):

You can get only coreboot for the motherboards it supports (i.e. the motherboards it is ported for), see the [doc](https://doc.coreboot.org/mainboard/index.html) and you have to compile it from the sourcecode by yourself and then [flash](https://doc.coreboot.org/flash_tutorial/index.html) it to the bios chip externally with a Raspberry Pi or internally. So is it difficult, probably not because I am just a regular GNU/Linux user and I was able to flash it to my coreboot supported machine with the help of #coreboot people on libera.Chat irc server and yes it supports Ubuntu and all its variants. Take a look into the [rookie guide](https://doc.coreboot.org/lessons/index.html).